# Understanding NGINX default caching

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a NGINX config with different locations. They all return an individual `index.html`. The `index.html`s are built with each deployment. They include `script` tags for JavaScript files that are delivered with a content hash in the file name, to bust the cache.

My problem is, that after a deployment, some of the required scripts are `404`ing because the downloaded `index.html` has the old content hash in the JS file names. It seems to be a problem with the way, the `index.html` is delivered, because it is an old version of the `index.html` that has been downloaded by the client.

This is an example location in my NGINX config:

```
location /my-route {
  try_files $uri /my-route/index.html;
}
```

When I inspect the response headers, I see an ETag for all index.html files. Shouldn't be that enough to ensure correct caching behavior for all `index.html` files?

My next approach would be adding an `Cache-Control` header. But I don't know if it would solve my problem, because I can't explain exactly why it would be the correct solution (but I would like to learn about it).

```
location /my-route {
  add_header Cache-Control "must-revalidate";
  try_files $uri /my-route/index.html;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an `expire` call anywhere?

Comment: Nope, only for some other resources (like PNG). Should I have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the cache-busting strategy to work for linked assets (JavaScript files etc), in the way that you described it,  you need to ensure that browsers always have a fresh copy of index.html.

Here is one conservative way to achieve what you need.
Setup a `location` block just for the HTML files and a separate location block for the the other assets that have the content hash in their filenames. For the HTML files you need:

```
add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
```

For the assets with the content hash in their filenames use:

```
add_header Cache-Control "max-age: 31536000";
```

To answer your question about whether sending ETags on your index.html files is enough, the answer is no. Without a Cache-Control header browsers use their own algorithm for deciding whether to retrieve from their own cache or to hit the network with a If-None-Match request header to validate the copy they already have.

Note: I am not familiar with try_files, but you will need to make sure that if try_files internally redirects to a different location block, that that final location block adds the correct headers.